# Change rootViewController of UIWindow animated

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is there a way to change the `rootViewController` of an `UIWindow` with a transition?

Comment: There are a few detailed answers to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703806/rootviewcontroller-switch-transition-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rootViewController is just a subview of your UIWindow. You can add other subviews and and do things like `transitionFromView:toView:...`.