# Objective-C : Change splitView orientation

Tags: orientation, uisplitviewcontroller, rootview

I currently have an authentication view controller defined as the rootViewController when the app starts. When the user is authenticated, the authentication view controller changes the rootViewController of the main windows to a split view controller.

My problem is when I happen to be in landscape mode and that it switches views, the split view is first show in portrait mode and the rotates to appear on landscape mode. What should I do to make it rotate like in background before appearing.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was. This thread solved my problem

[RootViewController animation transition, initial orientation is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053832/rootviewcontroller-animation-transition-initial-orientation-is-wrong)