# Wrong flip transition from fullscreen view without status bar to normal view with status bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

At the start, my application shows full screen view (320x480) without status bar. After a user do some selection, the app uses `+[UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:]` to switch to normal view with status bar. Unfortunately, during transition it seems that toView has size 320x480, so part of the view is below status bar. Just after transition completes, view is resized to 320x460 (as it should be initially).

My question is how can I force the view to be resized correctly before transition.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but not identical problem. Try the solution given here, which worked for me (basically, using setAnimationsEnabled: to disable part of the animation):

[RootViewController animation transition, initial orientation is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053832/rootviewcontroller-animation-transition-initial-orientation-is-wrong)

Comment: My problem is that I cannot make status bar to be a part of toView image. Manipulating with the hidden property of the status bar is delayed for some reason on iOS 5. My current solution is to not show status bar during transaction, but show it quickly after transaction done.