# Switching view by changing delegate rootViewContoller

Tags: objective-c, delegates, switching, rootview

I'm presently trying to switch view from a UIViewController to a SplitViewController. I'm currently doing this in my UIViewController:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[UIView transitionWithView:delegate.window duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    delegate.window.rootViewController = delegate.splitViewController;
} completion:nil];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Is it the right way to switch view ? If yes, I still have a problem to solve with that method.
It first quickly shows the MasterView in Portrait Mode and then show the whole split view in the current orientation mode of the iPad.

I hope I'm clear enough.

Thank for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work from that thread :

[RootViewController animation transition, initial orientation is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053832/rootviewcontroller-animation-transition-initial-orientation-is-wrong)

```
AppDelegate *delegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    delegate.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
 } 
 completion:nil];
```