# "Application tried to present Split View Controllers modally"

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am still trying to find a solution to what is theoretically a very simple task and that is going from a UIViewController to a Split View Controller. (Why have apple made this so difficult).

I am at a stage where I now put the SplitViewController into its own storyboard.
And when user selects a button on the single UIView Controller I call the following code:

```
UISplitViewController *splitVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SplitStoryBoard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewController];
    [self presentViewController:splitVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So I want to load the storyboard with the splitview controller.
But this also crashes with "Application tried to present Split View Controllers modally"

I did not specify any "modal" action in the code.

Is there any solution for how to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

The `UISplitViewController` has to be always the root view controller, and cannot be presented modally. See [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html), that says:

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from a
>   UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window. The panes of your split view interface may then contain
>   navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view
>   controller you need to implement your interface. Split view
>   controllers cannot be presented modally.

Comment: I can embed a SplitViewController into a TabViewController and segue to the TabViewController. Why are apple making such a big deal about this.

Comment: I don't know, but they are the guys who implemented all that stuff... If you don't follow their advices and rules, you will get sooner or later into trouble.

Comment: Does apple or anyone provide a pattern or have an idea of how to present views before you get to the split view?  IE login is a pretty common scenario. How would one present a regular login view and transition to the split view controller once logged in? Again if apple wants to to be root view controller of app probably not a good idea to violate that or workaround.

Comment: That's no longer true since iOS 8.

Comment: These is not true even iOS7,..You can present modally splitView, but you need to make the splitView rootController in awakeFromNib specifically in iOS7 as Alex says. In iOS 8 no need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a splitViewController as a view to a TabViewController, however a splitViewController cannot be a modal controller in the traditional sense. To transition to a SplitViewController from a UIViewController, use code like this:

```
- (IBAction)setupTapped:(id)sender {
    static NSString *tabViewControllerIdentifier = @"SetupViewController";  


    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:tabViewControllerIdentifier];
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIViewController *currentController = app.window.rootViewController;
    app.window.rootViewController = controller;
    app.window.rootViewController = currentController;

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view.window
                      duration:0.75
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:^{
                        app.window.rootViewController = controller;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}
```

That will transition between controllers. You can change the animation type to suit your purpose. This is set with the options parameter; currently showing UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight.

Comment: The animation transition didn't take effect for me at all. Is there a reason why you set the rootVC to the target view controller, and then back to the source before running the block?

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work using this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053832/rootviewcontroller-animation-transition-initial-orientation-is-wrong

Answer (score 1):

This one is quite old question. However I got it worked using below code in my app and I think it is better solution.

```
[self addChildViewController:<# Your Split VC #>];
[<# Your Split VC #>.view willMoveToSuperview:self.view];
<# Your Split VC #>.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:<# Your Split VC #>.view];
[<# Your Split VC #>.view didMoveToSuperview];
```

The idea is to take a view controller (Parent) and add split view controller as its child. Perform model segue to parent as you do for any other controller.

Well I am not sure but from iOS8 SplitViewController got lot better and it should be ok to use it somewhere else than root view controller.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you created  `UISplitViewController` in a storyboard, and when added main view before the split view, then you can use `performSegueWithIdentifier` to trigger a seque between main and split view.
To fix the bug in the caption you need to override one method in your `UISplitViewController`

```
// Swift
override func awakeFromNib() {
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    let currentController = app.window!.rootViewController;
    app.window!.rootViewController = self;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Obj-C?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible passing from UIView to UISplitView. You have to use a custom segue.

Read this link (translate it from japanese)

[UIViewController to UISplitViewController](http://cheesememo.blog39.fc2.com/blog-entry-465.html)