# Are views/viewcontrollers from stack destroyed when rootview changed in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my interrogation :

When my app starts a first view controller is loaded, then on top of it a login or signinUp view controller is loaded depending on user choice, then I replace the rootviewcontroller this way :

```
                    var vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProposeOrChooseViewController") as ProposeOrChooseViewController
                let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0] as UIWindow
                window.rootViewController = vc
                UIView.transitionFromView(
                    window.rootViewController!.view,
                    toView: vc.view,
                    duration: 0.65,
                    options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,
                    completion: {finished in

                        window.rootViewController = vc
                })
```

Are all the viewcontrollers/views destroyed and removed from the views stack when replacing the rooviewcontroller  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is a reference to a controller in your app delegate it will stay around.

I noticed in your code you actually set the root controller before you call `transitionFromView`? Not sure that looks correct?

There are a number of articles on how to do this scattered around. An issue seems to relate to making it work properly if the device is rotated.

[RootViewController animation transition, initial orientation is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053832/rootviewcontroller-animation-transition-initial-orientation-is-wrong)

This handy function seems to reflect the discussions and it is in swift:

https://gist.github.com/nvkiet/6368d1d45c4ea3e6d9cb

Comment: You were right I deleted the duplicated line where I set the root controller before the `transitionFromView`. And I added `window.rootViewController = nil` before to be sure there is no reference

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my guess is as soon as you lose the reference of your view controller or views, they will get destroyed.