# Removing ViewController after showing modally a second ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Guys in my app I have some code in the app delegate method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` that determines if the initial View Controller should be the `LoginViewController` or the `MainViewController`.

If the `LoginViewController` is showed first and the user logs in successfully I show the `MainViewController` modally with this piece of code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
FSMainViewController *vc = (MainViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
vc.loginViewController = self;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What I want to do next, after the `MainController` is showed on the screen, is remove the `LoginViewController` from memory so in the `viewWillApper:animated:` method of the `MainViewController` I use this code to remove (or at least try to) the `LoginViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.loginViewController) {
        [self.loginViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Problem is that this code leads to strange behaviors like the `MainViewController` being removed from the screen and this error message showing up in the console.

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <LoginViewController: 0xb06e350>
```

I also tried calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]` in the completion block of the `presentViewController:animated:completion` method but still no luck, it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong? How can I remove from memory the underlying `LoginViewController` when the `MainViewController` is presented modally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't present your main view controller if you want the login controller to go away, just make it the window's root view controller.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
FSMainViewController *vc = (MainViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
Self.window.rootViewController = VC;
```

Comment: This works but I would prefer the switching to be animated with some transition. Is there any way for doing that?

Comment: Found a way to animate it at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703806/rootviewcontroller-switch-transition-animation

Answer (score 0):

You can't `dismissViewController` after presenting another one on it or its `presentingViewController`. At here, you should dismiss `LoginViewController` first, then present `MainViewController`.

Otherwise, if you'd like `pushViewController`, you can call `[self.navigationController setViewControllers: animated:]` to remove `LoginViewController`.

If you think `presentingViewController` is just what you want, try something like this in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
if (self.loginViewController) { //Define loginViewController in appDelegate.h
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:mainViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
else{
    [self presentViewController:mainViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```