# setRootViewController animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have this code that I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26681430/1138498):

```
func changeRootViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {

    if self.window?.rootViewController == nil {
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        return
    }

    let snapShot = self.window?.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
    viewController.view.addSubview(snapShot!)
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

        snapShot?.layer.opacity = 0.0
        snapShot?.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)

        }) { (value: Bool) -> Void in

        snapShot?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

It works fine, but it only have one problem, when the animation is finished the UIActivityIndicatorView frame is changing or there is a some kind of 'kick' to the view.

You can see it in [THIS](https://youtu.be/4KR2ih8zytw) video.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did yu try the animation with completion `UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
 
}, completion: {
    (value: Bool) in
 
})`  and put  `snapShot?.removeFromSuperview()` in the competition block ?

Comment: Thats not what I did here?