# Changing root view controller in the background

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, dismiss, rootview

I have the following view controllers stack.

First, my app will show an app tour page. (Say `TourViewController` - super class is `UIViewController`). Added this controller in `AppDelegate` as rootviewcontroller.

```
self.window.rootViewController = tourViewController;
```

Then from the tour page, if the user taps on "Signin" button, I'm presenting the second view controller (Say `LoginViewController` - super class is `UIViewController`).

```
UINavigationController *loginNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.loginViewController];
[self presentViewController:loginNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After a successful login, I need to resign the second view controller (`LoginViewController`) and want to show a tab bar based view for further needs.

I tried this code inside the login success method.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        TabBarViewController *tabController = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];

        [self presentViewController:tabController animated:NO completion:nil];

        AppDelegate *applicationDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        applicationDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabController;

    }];
```

**Problems:**

- When I'm in the `LoginViewController`, I have two view controllers in my stack. So even I resign the `LoginViewController`, the another one (`TourViewController`) remains in the screen.
- If I tried the above code, tab bat controller was successfully added as root view controller. But, when the `LoginViewController` resigns, the background was filled by `TourViewController`

What I need is, When I resign the `LoginViewController`, the background view should be tab bar controller instead of `TourViewController`.

Help needed!!

Comment: simple solution is that, assign your `loginviewcontroller` as root view instead presenting it, and then when you login successful assign your `tabbarcontroller` as rootview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can change the root view controller in `AppDelegate` not in the success method of the `loginNavigationController` better u can do this way

in `AppDelegate.h`

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "TabControllerViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

- (void)showTabController;  //add this method call from on success method of log in completion 
@end
```

in `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (void)showTabController;
 {
   TabControllerViewController *tabController =    [[TabControllerViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"TabControllerViewController" bundle:nil];
  self.window.rootViewController = tabController;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and in `loginNavigationController.m`

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    //TabBarViewController *tabController = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];

  //  [self presentViewController:tabController animated:NO completion:nil]; //no nee to present 

    AppDelegate *applicationDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     [applicationDelegate showTabController]; //there is no need to create a tab bar in loginview controller, create it in root view controller 
    //applicationDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabController;

}];
```

NOTE: above is not tested just try it once

**Edit 1**

one way u can do it but with different animation, 
form this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703806/rootviewcontroller-switch-transition-animation) u can change to second window by doing some animation for example

in  in `AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TabViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window; //holds initial window, holds tour and login controller
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *tabWindow; //holds only tab controller 
//..other code below is my test 
@property (strong, nonatomic) TabViewController *tabViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) LoginViewController *loginController;
- (void)showTabController;
@end
```

in `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
   _tabWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
   _window    = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   _loginController = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
   _tabViewController = [[TabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = _loginController; //for test for your case it contains tour view controller  
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
 }

 - (void)showTabController;
 {
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
    self.window.rootViewController = _tabViewController;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      // [_tabWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    }];
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried this, its working fine but not fills but requirement. BTW, Should I always initiate the tab bar in AppDelegate?

Comment: yes  after login successful there is no need of loginview controller and app delegate is the one to hold your tabviewcontroller and in feature it makes easy to access your tabview controller form app delegate

Comment: Your code works fine with proper declaration of tab bar controller. But I want to show the tab bar controller as the background when my second controller (LoginViewController) resigns. Can you help in that?

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing,

Create `UINavigationController` in AppDelegate.h so you can access it anywhere.

**Logic**

Whenever you need to change navigation controller you must have to put your Controller to Navigation stack.

So first of all you have to create ViewController/ Tabbarcontroller object and assign it to navigationController and then show the navigationController.

```
AppDelegate* myDelegate = (((AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));
InitialViewController *initialVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“InitialVC"];
myDelegate.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:initialVC];
myDelegate.window.rootViewController = myDelegate.navController;
[myDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: that is not a problem

Comment: just you have to create object like init it.