# Deinit UITabBarController after presenting new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, deinit

I have an app in which users can log in. If the user launches the app and is already logged in then the `rootViewController` is set to my custom `UITabBarController` but when the user is not logged in the `rootViewController` is set to LoginVC (View Controller). My problem is that when the user logs out the LoginVC should be presented and the TabBar should be deinitialized.

I have tried:

```
self.tabBarController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    self.tabBarController?.present(LoginVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

And things like that... 
I can present the LoginVC but when I call `self.tabBarController?.dismiss`
the LoginVC gets dismissed instead of the TabBarVC

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to just set the `rootViewController` to the `LoginVC`. The reference to the `UITabBarController` will be lost and it will de-init.

Calling `dismiss` on a VC does not dismiss that VC.  It dismisses the VC it is presenting:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

> Dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the view controller.

Comment: Is there a way to animate that transition?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703806/rootviewcontroller-switch-transition-animation